# Listing urls from a csv file

Tags: python, url

I'm trying to list urls from a csv file to see what their HTTP code is. This is what ive got so far:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error

url = ['http://www.10vibes.info'
       'http://www.10vibes.info']

try:
    conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
    print(e.code)
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
    print('URLError')
else:
    print('good')
```

Comment: What errors are you getting or which part are you stuck on specifically?

Comment: url passed has to be a string. You are passing an array to `urllib.request.urlopen`.

Comment: Where is your code for reading a CSV file? This looks like a snippet of code you pulled from the internet that has nothing to do with the task you're trying to complete just to get us to code it for you.. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Pass url as string as follows:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.error

url = ['http://www.10vibes.info'
       'http://www.10vibes.info']

for my_url in url:
   try:
       conn = urllib.request.urlopen(my_url)
   except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
       # Return code error (e.g. 404, 501, ...)
       # ...
       print(e.code)
       pass
   except urllib.error.URLError as e:
       # Not an HTTP-specific error (e.g. connection refused)
       # ...
       print('URLError')
       pass

   print('good')
```

Comment: I only get one output in the shell. how would i go about listing the solutions